# How can all animals fit in Noah's ark

Tags: flood-of-noah, ark-of-noah

Genesis 6

> 14 So make yourself an ark of cypress[c] wood; make rooms in it and coat it with pitch inside and out. 15 This is how you are to build it: The ark is to be three hundred cubits long, fifty cubits wide and thirty cubits high.[d] 16 Make a roof for it, leaving below the roof an opening one cubit[e] high all around.[f] Put a door in the side of the ark and make lower, middle and upper decks.

Based on the specs, Noah's ark is around 2/3 of the size of  Titanic.

How can he possibly fit all the animals (assuming land and air) including all their sub species in that ark? Assuming around 2 Million different species exist (This is supposedly the lowest estimate). Considering also their food supply and water supply for almost a month. How is this possible? Is there any divine intervention(God's magic) on how all of these become plausible? And if there is, then why bother making a boat with a specification and go all the trouble doing all of the gathering and food allocation if God could had simply snap his fingers and all is in order again, is it because of God's limited powers that he needs Noah's help? But hes was able to build everything in the universe from scratch in 7 days.

Is there any references that explains if he did intervene or like shrink the animals inside the ark? Or was the ark like a trick boat which has almost unlimited space inside? Please provide biblical reference to this.

Thanks!

Comment: Dude, you've asked more duplicate questions than anybody I can remember in this history of the site. This one is almost an exact title match and I'm sure (because I tested it) that the system is showing you a message while you type in your question saying "**Questions that may already have your answer**" with the duplicate question at the top of the list. Please search the site on your own before starting and then actually read the questions shown in this list as you ask.